# inner joined based on every attribute

Tags: sql, netezza

I know I can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b ON (table_a.attribute = table_b.attribute)
```

To do an inner join based on the same attributes in `table_a` and `table_b`.

But what if I have over 100 attributes and I want to do an inner join only when all the attributes are the same. Is there an easier way than to list on all 100+?

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b ON 
(table_a.attribute1 = table_b.attribute1 and 
table_a.attribute2 = table_b.attribute2 and 
table_a.attribute3 = table_b.attribute3 ... and
table_a.attribute100 = table_b.attribute100)
```

Use Aginity+Excel to create the join faster :)

Answer (score 0):

If the attributes are the same you can use NATURAL JOIN. It's not one I've actually used but it should do exactly What you want.  E.g http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html.

Comment: Natural join can be used in ad hoc queries, but never in programming. (If a column name changes, applications quit to work as expected...)